# How to disable caching in VB6 using WebBrowser control?

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, vb6, webbrowser-control

I use this piece of code:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate (url)

Dim html As String
html = WebBrowser1.Document.body.innerhtml
```

And in the html of the page I even put the meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

I tried doing as suggested here on similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421144/how-to-disable-caching-in-the-net-webbrowser-control) but neither of that helped for VB6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate url, 4
```

The 4 turns off caching.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Maybe a link?

Comment: The magic number `4` is defined as `navNoReadFromCache` and you should use that.  Source?  Documented right in the MSDN Library CDs that came with my copy of Visual Studio 6.0.  Should be available at MSDN online as well.

Comment: Bob - sadly, the documentation for the original COM WebBrowser control has disappeared online.

Comment: @BobRiemersma Every page I found with `navNoReadFromCache` says it is not implemented. Ex: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd565688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768360(v=vs.85).aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565688(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: And hard-coding the magic number *is* implemented, hmm?  Why Micrososft left it out of the typelib I couldn't say, but you are expected to include the Enum yourself, inline within your programs. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565688(VS.85).aspx