# Magento 2 install issue (php 7.0.32) on windows 10

Tags: magento, xampp, windows-10

magento version : Magento-CE-2.2.6-2018-09-07-02-07-16
PHP : 7.0.32
this message shown in system.log

> "C:/xampp/htdocs/mag/generated/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/PayflowlinkFactory.php.11336"
>   cannot be renamed into
>   "C:/xampp/htdocs/mag/generated/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/PayflowlinkFactory.php"
>   Warning!rename(C:/xampp/htdocs/mag/generated/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/PayflowlinkFactory.php.11336,C:/xampp/htdocs/mag/generated/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/PayflowlinkFactory.php):
>   The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process. (code: 32)
>       Class Magento\Paypal\Model\PayflowlinkFactory generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated'
>   directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the
>   'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated'
>   directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not
>   generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the
>   signature of the related construct method, only. [] []

Comment: Any news on this issue?

Comment: it's fixed. I didn't change any configuration back then. the current release is installing easily. I don't know why it happened. probably version issue. thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's fixed. I didn't change any configuration back then. the current release is installing easily. Ii was probably version issue. thanks for asking.

Answer (score -2):

Rename the file from PayflowlinkFactory.php.11336 to PayflowlinkFactory.php . It may works!

Reference: [Renaming File Error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23847225/renaming-file-error-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used)

Comment: The error message says "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (code: 32". A simple rename wont solve the problem

Comment: this was some PHP version issue may be, But I still don't have the correct answer.